# The plot thickens... here's another one!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am sometimes in clothes or in dairy,

When seen, the wise are oft wary,

Not something they'd like to step upon,

You'll want to get this one in one.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are

> A hole

I am sometimes in clothes or in dairy

> Clothes can have holes in them if damaged, and some kinds of cheese have holes (famously, Swiss cheese)

When seen, the wise are often wary,
Not something they'd like to step upon,

> You don't want to fall into a hole

You'll want to get this one in one

> A hole-in-one is the best score you can get in golf

Comment: You got it dood.  +1